# How to integrate PayUMoney in core php

Tags: php, payumoney

Hi I am new to **`PHP`** and I want to integrate the **`PayUMoney`** with core **`PHP`**.  Can anyone tell me how to do the integration of **`PayUMoney`** in core **`PHP`**.
Here is my code

Controller:

```
<?php       
    $results = $db->query("SELECT * FROM courses");
    while($row = $results->fetch_assoc())
    {
   ?>
   <img src="images/<?php echo $row['image'];  ?>" style = "width:20%;"/>
   <br/><strong>Course:</strong> <?php echo $row['name']; ?>
   <strong>Price:</strong> <?php echo $row['price']; ?>
   <form action="http://www.payumoney.com" method="post">

   <input type="hidden" name="business" value="ashalatha.cse76@gmail.com">

   <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">

   <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $row['price']; ?>">
   <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">

   <input type="image" name="submit" border="0" style="width:9%;"
   src="buynow.png" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online">
   <img alt="" border="0" width="1" height="1" src="" >

   </form>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: So, what are issues that you are facing in your code. Please explain your issue properly

Comment: If i click on buy now option it is redirecting to www.payu,com, https://github.com/PayU/openpayu_php from this site i downloaded  code but not able to integrate in my code if i click on buy now it should redirect to payment page.

Comment: Can anyone help me regarding this payu gateway

Answer (score 0):

This OpenPayu sdk is only for polish market. You can change configuration in link below https://github.com/PayU/openpayu_php/blob/master/lib/OpenPayU/Configuration.php
and adjust to parametres.

Comment: While this may provide an answer, it would be better to incorporate it in your actual answer, since the link might be dead in the future.